# What is best parition format and raid setup for millions of small files?

Tags: hard-disk, performance, raid, ssd, storage

If I have millions of small files distributed by folders, what would be the best parition format and what raid setup in order to manage them as fast as possible ? E.g search in all files, find files larger than x MB, etc.

Will it help in this scenario to have 4-5 SSDs distributed in raid for performance ?

And considering most files are under 1 MB, is there a certain partition format that would perform faster in this case ?

**Edit:** data will be read multiple times to make queries, so at least twice as many reads than writes. Data is not critical and speed is a priority over data protection.

Comment: What percentage of your operations will be read vs write?  And what are your data integrity requirements?  Will single parity suffice?  double parity?  or do you need mirrors?  Or do you just need raw speed, and if something goes wrong you can recreate the data set?

Comment: Maybe twice as many reads than writes. Speed is priority over data protection/integrity, data is not critical. Something like analyzing big data sets (that can be re-created). I will add this to question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general for RAID, you get get N(number of devices) * I(iops) for reads, and some division takes place for writes depending on RAID level.  (N*I)/2 for mirrors, /4 for raid5, /6 for raid6, etc.

For non-critical data, that can be lost in the event of a device failure, and recreated from scratch, or just be created new, RAID0 will be the fastest for writes.  That's a simple stripe across multiple devices, and there are no parity reads or writes taking place to consume Write Iops.  In RAID0, both read and write performance should be N*I.  (your CPU and the filesystem of choice's caching methods, may affect numbers a bit, but as a general rule, you should get pretty close to that.

Depending on the number of drives you have available, and the capacity you need, using RAID10 will keep your read performance at N*I and your write performance will be (N*I)/2 since you have to issue writes to both sides of the mirror.

4-5 SSDs, configured as a stripe, using EXT4, will give you (in my opinion) the best intersection of Performance and Simplicity, sacrificing data protection.

RAID10 will halve your capacity, and your write performance, maintain your read performance (you can still read from all the drives), and give you good data integrity.

For scratch data, I would use EXT4 and RAID0, on a single partition, and multiple folders as needed.